# How do I set permissions to use Docker with my normal user?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, docker, chmod

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I use docker to run images. When I installed and ran the docker command for the 1st time, the following error occurred in the shell.

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

I ran `sudo chmod 766 /var/run/docker.sock` and it worked. However, whenever I restart the system, I have the permission denied again and I need to run chmod again.

How do I resolve this issue? I want to have root access always when running docker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add your user to the docker group by running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

the new group membership will be applied to your user after logging out and back in again.

For reference, see the [official docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine)